# Display an array in a blade template from Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I give an array to a view

```
$data = array('data' => array(
                            'name' => 'Name',
                            'age' => 'Age'
                        )
);

return View::make('hello')->with('data', $data);
```

In the view.blade.php i'd like to do

```
{{ $data['name'] }}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an array inside of an array

```
{{{ $data['data']['name'] }}}
```

or change your array construction to

```
$data = array('name' => 'Name',
              'age' => 'Age');
```

then you can just do

```
 {{{ $data['name'] }}}
```

Comment: Ahahah you"re right. I have a more complex structure as i showed you, thats the reason why there is an array in a array. But as I have too many name 'data' i was lost :)

Comment: @The Shift Exchange Would you please provide any laravel documentation link for the above answer and also please provide version if specific.